# Protect Android .txt file with password

Tags: android, encryption

I was wondering if there is any way to programmatically protect an Android .txt file with password?

I have heard of encrypting methods for this, but don't have a clue how to do it?

Can somebody suggest me something? And maybe shere some examples?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Sebastian.  Welcome to SO.  At the moment your question is off-topic and will likely attract downvotes.  I suggest you have a read of the [help] to get a feel for what is on topic here and what isn't.  If you have attempted the problem yourself, please post a [mcve] and we can help you to debug it.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this web page which require a key that only you will know to encrypt your text then save it in a file. Then decrypt it using the same key:

https://www.fourmilab.ch/javascrypt/javascrypt.html

But yeah if you want to programmatically do it yourself, you gotta learn a lot of thing. There is a ton of encrypting method and many library already made for most coding languages so if you know any, just google 'encrypting a text file in javascript' for example.

Here is a link to a program that can do it for android:
http://www.guidingtech.com/12457/encrypt-password-protect-files-android/

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions that are off-topic.  The OP is looking for code, not for a tool.  Additionally, this is more of comment than an answer.